# Problemas para hacer una gráfica utilizando highcharts y bottle en python

Tags: python, json, highcharts, bottle

Estoy utilizando `bottle` para obtener datos por medio de un `query` de una base de datos en `sql server`, con dichos datos estoy intentando hacer un gráfico pastel utilizando `highcharts` y `json`, mi código es el siguiente:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT @@version;")
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
    print (row[0])
    row = cursor.fetchone()

@route('/prueba_grafico')
def index():
    c.execute("exec insumo_medico")
    result = c.fetchall()
    for raw in result:
        cant_total = raw[0]
        cant_desabastecidos = raw[1]
        cant_normal = raw[2]
        cant_sobre_stock = raw[3]

    parametros = {
        'chart': {
            'plotBackgroundColor': None,
            'plotBorderWidth': None,
            'plotShadow': False,
            'type': 'pie'
        },
        'title': {
            'text': 'ESTADO DE STOCK DE MEDICAMENTOS'
        },
        'tooltip': {
            'pointFormat': '{series.name}: <b>{point.y:.1f}</b>'
        },
        'plotOptions': {
            'pie': {
                'allowPointSelect': True,
                'cursor': 'pointer',
                'dataLabels': {
                    'enabled': True,
                    'format': '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                }
            }
        },
        'series': [{
            'name': 'Brands',
            'colorByPoint': 'true',
            'data': [{
                'name': 'Insumos Medicos Desabastecidos',
                'y': cant_desabastecidos,
                'sliced': 'true',
                'selected': 'true'
            }, {
                'name': 'Insumos Medicos NormoStock',
                'y': cant_normal
            }, {
                'name': 'Insumos Medicos SobreStock',
                'y': cant_sobre_stock
            }, ]
        }]
    };
    parametros = json.dumps(parametros)

    output = template('grafic_test', rows=result)

    return ((dict(parametros=parametros)),output)




run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

como es sabido, con `fetchall()` obtengo una `tupla` dentro de una lista, para ello uso una variable `raw` para obtener los datos de la `tupla`, ya que solo habrá una sola `tupla` en la lista.

este es mi template:

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 300px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var parametros = JSON.parse('{{=XML(parametros)}}');
        $('#container').highcharts(parametros);
    });
</script>
```

y el error que me aparece es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quisiera saber si mi problema es mi código o mi templare o estoy configurando algo mal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como el error indica, los decimales no pueden ser serializados usando `json.dumps`. Puedes convertirlos a `string` o `float` según necesites:

```
>>> import json
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> json.dumps({'x': Decimal('100.00')})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 244, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: Decimal('100.00') is not JSON serializable
>>> json.dumps({'x': str(Decimal('100.00'))})
'{"x": "100.00"}'
>>> json.dumps({'x': float(Decimal('100.00'))})
'{"x": 100.0}'
```

En tu caso, me parece que necesitas hacerlo con alguna de las siguientes variables de tu código (no sé cuál de ellas es un decimal) antes de pasarlas por el dump:

```
cant_total = float(raw[0])
cant_desabastecidos = float(raw[1])
cant_normal = float(raw[2])
cant_sobre_stock = float(raw[3])
```

Otra opción es usar tu propio [`encoder`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4019897/688393).